# how to connect applewatch os1 with xcode 7.1 simulator

Tags: xcode, apple-watch

I want to run my apple watchkit(OS1) app on a watchsimulator, but i could not connect my app simulator becuase i could not find watch option on the external diplay. my app ios is 9.1 and my xcode is 7.1.1. onother issue here is i can not see applewatch OS1 as an option in xcode 7.1 when i try to add new simulator device.
my question is:
1. why cann't i see the the applewatch on external display? (possible reason)
2. Is it possible to run Applewatch OS 1 using xcode 7.1?
[here is thedisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0UZs.png)